# python call method from external function of class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a function where an application is already created but I can't edit

```
class mainProject():
     def __init__(self, screen):
          module1 = importlib.import_module(extension)
          module1.openBox()


     def boxIsOpen(self):
          .......
```

I try to execute boxIsOpen() into my custom function openBox() in the extension module.

It is possible to do that? I try to reinitialized the class into the function but it is not the previous function. The "caller" keyword don't really works.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason that you're trying to import `module1` indisde `mainProject.__init__()`? If you import it there, it won't be accessible to the function `boxIsOpen`. You should probably import it at a file level.

Comment: @danielu13, thanks for your response, its just a little example. I won't send the full .py. I just swrink and edit some part to keep the essential. Like, the importLib and my external function.

Comment: When you say the application is already created... I have a feeling you're doing something very, very bad. Can you confirm that you're trying to edit add functions to a Python class at runtime? This should (almost) never be necessary for most people...

Comment: Especially because you may end up with different code for the individual instances (if there are any) of `mainProject`; I'm not even sure that's possible.

Comment: Its a project for my client. We have a file and I need to add a function (its a def who's called by the class.) just want to know if its possible to get some function from the class called. In reality, the class has a function to know if user have access or not.. I want to use this function in my code but like I said.. it is in the class that I dont have access.

Comment: If you just need a function from a class called, you could just create an instance of the class and call the function (or without an instance it if it's a static function). Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, importing in the middle of code, let alone in a constructor isn't advisable.

```
import extension
class mainProject():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        extension.openBox()

    def boxIsOpen(self):
        ...
```

Should do the trick.

If you cannot touch the original otherwise, you should consider subclassing `mainProject` instead.